# C++ XAML Selected Item from ComboBox

Tags: xaml, combobox, c++-cx

I'm currently trying to create a simple C++ Windows Phone 8.1 application for myself, and am stuck with this simple problem. I couldn't find any examples of similar code for C++, only for C#.

My code is based on a simple ["Hello world"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263168.aspx) program. In the Mainpage.xaml I have introduced the following ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="AttackDice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70"   
              Margin="37,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"   
              Width="320">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One attack dice"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two attack dice" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Three attack dice" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Four attack dice"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Five attack dice"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Six attack dice"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I also have simple button, which triggers the following event in my Mainpage.xaml.cpp

```
void HelloWorld::MainPage::RollDice_Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender,
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    AttackResultTextBlock->Text = "Number of dice rolled: "
 + AttackDice->SelectedItem->ToString();
}
```

The code is supposed to retrieve the selected ComboBoxItem, and output the selected number of (attack) dice. However, the output is:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem

In C#, the correct way to do it would be (according to some guide I've found online)

```
Text = ((ComboBoxItem)AttackDice.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

but I'm not sure how to do it in C++.

Comment: Presumably, this should be `(safe_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(AttackDice->SelectedItem))->Content->ToString()`.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, that worked! I guess you should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C# code

```
Text = ((ComboBoxItem)AttackDice.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

can be converted to C++/CX. The equivalent of the cast in C# (see [Casting and Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)), which throws an `InvalidCastException` on failure, is [safe_cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23b7yy6w.aspx) in C++/CX:

```
Text = (safe_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(AttackDice->SelectedItem))->Content->ToString();
```